# How to protect endpoints from public access on aws-alb-ingress-controller?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Is there a way to protect endpoints from public access and/or only a list of IPs to have access to it like on nginx-ingress-controller (NLB) with the snippet-server annotation?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Nginx-ingress has annotation [whitelist-source-range](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range)

> You can specify allowed client IP source ranges through the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range` annotation. The value is a comma separated list of [CIDRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), e.g. `10.0.0.0/24,172.10.0.1`.

For access control in LoadBalancer you could use following annotation:
`alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs`

> specifies the CIDRs that are allowed to access LoadBalancer.

Example:

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs: 10.0.0.0/24
```

**this annotation will be ignored if  `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups`  is specified.**

Also [`alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups`](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/ingress/annotation/#security-groups) which  specifies the securityGroups you want to attach to LoadBalancer.

> When this annotation is not present, the controller will automatically create 2 security groups: the first security group will be attached to the LoadBalancer and allow access from [`inbound-cidrs`](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/ingress/annotation/#inbound-cidrs) to the [`listen-ports`](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/ingress/annotation/#listen-ports). The second security group will be attached to the EC2 instance(s) and allow all TCP traffic from the first security group created for the LoadBalancer.

Example:

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-xxxx, nameOfSg1, nameOfSg2
```